# How to compress multiple images size while uploading imaged using php?

Tags: php

Below is my code which I tried but there is showing some warning errors:

> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php2F0B.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\maahima\admin\uploadBulkImages.php on line 55
>
> Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maahima\admin\uploadBulkImages.php on line 66

I want the code to insert images in folder in bulk with compressed image.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    $pro_image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $no_of_file = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $name = ''; $type = ''; $size = ''; $error = '';

    for($i=0;$i < $no_of_file;$i++){
        if(! is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i])){
            header("location:add_products.php?error=er8r5r");
        }
        else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],"../products/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i])){
                if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] > 0) { 
                    $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
                }
                else {
                    $image="";
                    $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";
                    $url = '../smallSize-Image/'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                    echo  $url;
                    $source_url=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                    $destination_url=$url;
                    $quality=12;
                    $info = getimagesize($source_url);

                    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
                    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
                        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
                    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
                        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
                    
                    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
                    return $destination_url;

                    $buffer = file_get_contents($url);
                    /* Force download dialog... */
                    //header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
                    //header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                    //header("Content-Type: application/download");
                    // header("location:add_products.php?succcess=s8sc5s");
                    /* Don't allow caching... */
                    //  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                    /* Set data type, size and filename */
                    //header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                    //header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer));
                    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$url");
                    /* Send our file... */
                    echo $buffer;
                }
            }
            else{
                header("location:add_products.php?error=er8r5r");
            }
        }  
    }
}
else{
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you got proper form tag in your HTML form? Does it have  enctype= multipart/form-data ?

Answer (score 1):

Your script has a lot of illogical features. If you are going to redirect, you need to `exit`. You should not have a `return` in the middle of the script, that is somewhat random (probably this is unfinished script and it's inside another function/method?). Here are some things I would do if I were to do this.

If you don't already have a config that has some absolute defines, I would create one and include it on every initial load page at the top.

This is tested and works, provided it's implemented correctly and as demonstrated. Use some of it, bits of it, or none of it, but it does work:

**/config.php**

```
<?php
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('UPLOAD_DIR',ROOT_DIR.DS.'uploads'.DS.'images');
define('THUMB_DIR',ROOT_DIR.DS.'uploads'.DS.'thumbs');
define('VENDOR_DIR',ROOT_DIR.DS.'vendors');
```

I would consider making some quick functions, in this case a class/method system to complete some simple tasks.

**/vendors/Files.php**

```
class Files
    {
        /*
        ** @description This will turn a numbered $_FILES array to a normal one
        */
        public  static  function normalize($key = 'file')
            {
                foreach($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'] as $fKey => $value) {
                    $FILES[]    =   array(
                        'tmp_name'=>$_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'][$fKey],
                        'name'=>$_FILES[$key]['name'][$fKey],
                        'error'=>$_FILES[$key]['error'][$fKey],
                        'size'=>$_FILES[$key]['size'][$fKey],
                        'type'=>$_FILES[$key]['type'][$fKey]
                    );
                }

                return $FILES;
            }
        /*
        ** @description I would contain this step into an editable method for
        **              ease of use and reuse.
        */
        public  static  function compress($path, $dest, $quality = 12)
            {
                $info   =   getimagesize($path);

                if($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
                    $image  =   imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
                elseif($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
                    $image  =   imagecreatefromgif($path);
                elseif($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
                    $image  =   imagecreatefrompng($path);

                imagejpeg($image,$dest,$quality);
            }
    }
```

Put it all together, in this case I would maybe throw exceptions and save errors to a session. Loop through them on the `add_products.php` page.

```
# Add our config
include(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
# Add our file handler class (spl_autoload_register() is a better option)
include(VENDOR_DIR.DS.'Files.php');
# Observe for file upload
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    # Use our handy convert method
    $FILES      =   Files::normalize();
    # Try here
    try {
        # Loop through our normalized file array
        foreach($FILES as $i => $file){
            # Throw error exception here
            if(!is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']))
                throw new Exception('File is not an uploaded document.');
            # I like to add a create directory line or two to cover all bases
            if(!is_dir(UPLOAD_DIR)) {
                if(!mkdir(UPLOAD_DIR,0755,true))
                    throw new Exception('Upload folder could not be created.');
            }
            # Ditto
            if(!is_dir(THUMB_DIR)) {
                if(!mkdir(THUMB_DIR,0755,true))
                    throw new Exception('Thumb folder could not be created.');
            }
            # Create an absolute path for the full size upload
            $path   =   UPLOAD_DIR.DS.$file['name'];
            # If no errors and file is moved properly, compress and save thumb
            if(($file["error"]) == 0 && move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$path))
                # Create a thumbnail from/after the file you moved, not the temp file
                Files::compress($path,THUMB_DIR.DS.$file['name']);
            # Throw error on fail
            else
                throw new Exception('An unknown upload error occurred.');
        }
    }
    # Catch, assign, redirect
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $_SESSION['errors'][]   =   $e->getMessage();
        header("location: add_products.php?error=er8r5r");
        exit;
    }
}
```